# how to insert data in multiple tables using transaction

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

my first tables unique key is a foreign key in sub-table  and i am using transactions in stored procedure ,problem when i use transaction then first tables unique key being inserted shows no value before committing the query and for second table's data insertion i need unique key of row being inserted in first table.
i would use a select query with where clause .
but my interviewer said tell me some other way to achieve that ,he said he could not write "select where " statement for 100 tables.

Comment: use loop in procedure. Show me you code, maybe i can help you

Answer (score 3):

In such cases you would use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) function to retrieve the identity of the newly inserted row in parent table. Your script should look like this:

```
begin transaction
declare @parentId int;
insert into ParentTable(Value1, Value2) values('1', '2')

select @parentId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
insert into ChildTable(ParentId, Value) values(@parentId, '3')
commit
```

Comment: wow that's sounds nice but can i use this scope identity when isIdentity is set to false on primary key column.

Comment: because for unique primary key ,i used own logic to create pk not using identity column

Comment: @BRBHARDWAJ, if you create PK values with custom logic then you don't need `scope_identity()`. Just pass the `@parentId` as a parameter to your stored procedure.